# Pass Parameters in Link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to pass a parameter through a `link_to` method in Rails. I know there is a way to do it via the URL but I really don't want to do that. Is there any way to pass a param via a link without adding it to the link itself?

I know in PHP you can post and then retrieve that value by using the post variable. Is there something similar in Rails?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`link_to` signature looks as follows:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So, POST would look like (lets say you want to POST user's data):

```
link_to "Link text", some_path(:foo => "bar", :baz => "quux"), user: @user, :method => :post
```

User's data can be retrieved in the controller using `params[:user]`

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can pass a parameter around via the link_to method in order to, say, create a new object with the passed parameter. This strategy would allow you to pass variables among actions in your controller and create objects with predefined attributes:

Say in your *show* view, you have a variable called *@foo* that you want to pass to your *new* controller action.  In which case, in your *show* view, you can have

```
<%= link_to "Link Text", new_widget_path(:foo => @foo) %>
```

which would store @foo in params[:foo], allowing you to use params[:foo] in your controller. Which controller action you get directed to depends upon *new_widget_path*. In this case, you get directed to the *new* action in WidgetController.

Clicking on *Link Text* will direct Rails to the *new* action of your WidgetController. You can have

```
def new
  @widget = Widget.new(:foo => params[:foo])
end
```

Then, in your *new.html.erb* view file, you can allow the user to create a new Widget object with this pre-defined *foo* attribute already filled out via a hidden form field:

```
 <%= form_for(@widget) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :other_attribute %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :other_attribute %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :foo %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Allowing the user to create a new widget with the *foo* attribute already filled out!

Comment: What is amazing about this solution is that it is so detailed and clearly explained.  Thanks so much for posting.  Still useful a year later.

Comment: This example still does not show how to 'hide' params in url after clicking link_to, before getting to form on new page.

Answer (score 3):

Passing information through a web request can be done either by the URL: `http://example.com/foo?bar=blah` in a GET request which is what link_to does, or through a POST operation which usually requires a form.   The form could have hidden elements if you just want a submit button:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/foo">
  <input type="hidden" name="bar" value="blah">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

There are various rails helpers to help build the form if needed.

Lastly, if you *really* want a link, you could either CSS style that button, or you could use javascript to observe a link and then POST the info. (the method Simon Bagreev posted does this with javascript)

Comment: Thank you. I could not figure out why Simon Bagreev solution would work. Now, I have to look for explanation in CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of parameter? If it's a key for a GET request, convention would dictate using the url (e.g. params[:id] or a an active record path variable). If you want to POST something, you should be using a form. Otherwise, you could write a helper method to set a session variable or something, but think about your architecture and what you're *semantically* trying to do, and I'm sure someone here can help you out.

Comment: In essence it is a GET request, so I should probably not do what I want to do and just follow convention. Currently, I have my routes pretty nested -- already using about 6 segments in the URL. I was trying to avoid using the URL to put another few segments.