# New instance with filled in fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `form_for @transaction`, which renders a new form with empty fields for creating new `Transaction`.

Now I want to allow users to redo transaction.
So, user has a lot of transaction. And every transaction has a "Redo transaction" link.
When user clicks on this link, I want the same form for new `Transaction` renders, but with filled in fields from `Transaction`, which user wants to redo.

Now in my `transaction_controller.rb` I have this:

```
def new
  @transaction = current_user.transactions.new
  @repeat_transaction = current_user.transactions.new(params[:transaction])
end
```

link for redo `Transaction` in `_transaction.rb` view is:

```
<%= link_to(content_tag(:i, '', class: 'icon-repeat'),
            new_transaction_path(@repeat_transaction),
            class: 'transaction_redo_icon',
            style: 'display: none;',
            remote: true) %>
```

Now it renders an empty form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of **link_to** and **render** via the *edit* controller action. If you want to use the same form in *new* as you do in *edit*, use a partial, which can be invoked via *render*. See more on partials [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html).

To "redo" the transaction, you create an *edit* controller action (along with its corresponding *edit* view). The link to "Redo Transaction" should be along the lines of:

```
<%= link_to "Redo Transaction", edit_transaction_path %>
```

in, say, your *show* view.

Then in your *edit* view, you can render a partial called, say, *_form.html.erb* in your *views* folder by including

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

in your *edit* view, which would call up the code in the partial _form.html.erb. This partial could then contain the same form as the one you use on your *new*. In fact, your *new* view could also include this render statement, making your code DRY, and it would render the same form in *new* as it does in *edit*, except with your form fields already filled in with your attributes in the case of *edit*. Rails does the filling out for you.

**EDIT:**

In the case of making a **new** transaction record with filled in attributes, you can follow my post on [Pass Parameters in Link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378789/pass-parameters-in-link-to/17841232#17841232), except you would not necessarily have to hide the form field(s) that you want to fill in with attributes.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to edit the existed transaction. I want to create new, but with the same parameters, as existed one. Also, I want to allow users to change some parameters, that's why I want to render form with filled in fields, not for existed transaction, but for new one. As I see, when click on `submit` button in `edit` from, Rails will call `update` action, but I need to call the `create` action.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you can follow my post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378789/pass-parameters-in-link-to/17841232#17841232

Answer (score 1):

Your **Redo link** will be like the following

```
<%= link_to "Redo transaction", new_transaction_path(@transaction) %>
```

And rewrite your controller new method, like

```
def new
  @transaction = params[:id] ? current_user.transactions.new : current_user.transactions.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

Comment: But I don't want to edit the existed transaction, I want to render a new transaction form, but with the same parameters, as the existed one. So, when user clicks on `submit` button, I need to create a new transaction instead of update existed one.

Comment: @PeterTretyakov : See my answer. I have edited as u needed..It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The rails guides has specific examples for this case.

Summary:
For new object, on view

```
<%= form_for(Model.new) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :field_name %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Would render a new form and the input boxes tied to the form fields.

For an existing object, on view

```
<%= form_for(@object_instance) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :field_name %> <!-- this will populate it with database content and leave open for editing -->
  ...
<% end %>
```

See this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object)

Hope this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dup` for the existed object to duplicate the object existed .

```
def new
  @transaction = Transaction.new
  @transaction = current_user.transactions.find(params[:id]).dup 
end
```

and link can be

```
<%= link_to "Redo transaction", new_transaction_path(@transaction) %>
```