# Ruby On Rails - New model object through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have three models "Event", "Team", and "User" with various ActiveRecord Associations and am having trouble creating a new Event object and associating it with a team_id. Perhaps I am missing something with the relationships. They are defined as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :events, through: :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :users
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :users, through: :teams
end

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = current_team.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save
      flash[:success] = "Event created!"
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @team = Team.new
  end

  def create
    @team = current_user.teams.build(team_params)
    if @team.save
      flash[:success] = "Team created!"
      redirect_to @team
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The error is triggered in the events controller when I submit the create new event form, as current_team.events isn't recognized. I am relatively new to RoR so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on. I was trying to define current_team the same way one would define current_user, however, current_user is simply the one user in the current logged-in session.

Thus, I went a different route and passed the team_id parameter in the link_to the form for a new event. This allowed me to call the team_id in a hidden_field in the form and save it to the DB.

The method is explained quite well in this response: [Pass Parameters in Link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378789/pass-parameters-in-link-to)

Thanks for all of the help!

Events Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
 def new
    @event = Event.new(:team_id => params[:team_id])
 end

 def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
      flash[:success] = "Event created!"
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render 'new'
    end
 end

 private

  def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:date, :name, :location, :venue, :team_id)
    end
end
```

link:

```
<%= link_to "Create new event", newevent_path(:team_id => @team.id), class: "btn btn-md" %>
```

hidden field in form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :team_id %>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that `current_team` is not defined in your `EventsController`. If you get the team id from the form, you could do something like this:

```
current_team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
```

And then it should work.

Comment: Current_user is never defined in the team controller, is this because current_user is implicitly defined in rails?

Comment: It is usually the devise gem that will bring this functionality, but it would be current_user, not current_team!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an join table between User and Team? From that example you have many-to-many relationship between these two models but I dont see the relationship defined. Check the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: I do have a team_user join table. Currently, I don't have an issue creating teams and users.

Answer (score 0):

In the Team model, as it the join table you should do the following

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :event
      belongs_to :user
end
```

In the Event model :

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :users, through: :teams
end
```

Still I don't know if that what you really wants, if Team table is a join table and you want it to act like one, then this should be fine, but I suggest you check your relations again and also checking rails guide to completely understand what you have to do here

Comment: I'd like for the team_id to be passed along when an event is created so events can be indexed by team, and those events being displayed on the respective team pages. I'll keep digging in the rails guide, thanks.

Comment: That's great, then your models associations should work.
Check if you have a Team foreign key in the Event table, it can be created through a migration

Comment: The foreign key is in the event table. The issue seems to be NoMethodErrors in the Event Controller, not recognizing the team_id or events in current_team.events.build.