# NoMethodError in TasksController#create when creating new task from project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, nomethoderror

I have a projects model and a task model, however a task can have many projects and vice versa...so i created a relationship model between the two.  Now from the project profile, i want to be able to create a task and automatically have it create the task *and* the relationship between the new task and the project it was created from.

However when i try to accomplish this i am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in TasksController#create
undefined method `related?' for nil:NilClass
```

My Tasks Controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @task = current_user.own_tasks.build(task_params)
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Your task has been created."
      redirect_to @task
      @project.relate!(@task) unless @project.related?(@task) # establishes task relationship w/ project only if relationship doesn't already exist
    else
      render 'task'
    end
  end

private

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, taskrelationship_attributes: [:taskproject_id, :projecttask_id])
end

end
```

My TaskRelationship Model:

```
class TaskRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taskproject, class_name: "Project"
  belongs_to :projecttask, class_name: "Task"
  validates :taskproject_id, presence: true
  validates :projecttask_id, presence: true
end
```

My Task Model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :foreign_key=>'user_id', :class_name=>'User'

  has_many :reverse_taskrelationships, foreign_key: "projecttask_id",
                                   class_name: "TaskRelationship",
                                   dependent: :destroy
  has_many :taskprojects, through: :reverse_taskrelationships, source: :taskproject

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

end
Project Model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :foreign_key=>'user_id', :class_name=>'User'

  has_many :tasks
  has_many :taskrelationships, foreign_key: "taskproject_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projecttasks, through: :taskrelationships, source: :projecttask

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :background, presence: true

  def related?(some_task)
   taskrelationships.find_by_projecttask_id(some_task.id)
  end

  def relate!(some_task)
   self.taskrelationships.create!(projecttask_id: some_task.id)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong... thx,

UPDATE:

I've added the following line at the top of the create method as marsAtomic pointed out was missing...

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: I just misunderstand whats `own_tasks` in `current_user.own_tasks.build` ?

Comment: ah...i basically have in the user model has_many :own_projects, :class_name=>'Project'  and also 
  has_many :own_tasks, :class_name=>'Task'  (this is to associate the task or the project with an 'owner')

Comment: you could you just `current_user.tasks.build(task_params)`

Comment: is your routes Nested ? with `resources :projects do resources :tasks end` ?

Comment: no i didn't nest the route because I didn't necessarily want to create a task directly on a project...i wanted to just create a TaskRelationship (between the task & project...and keep the task and project totally separate objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at the error:

```
undefined method `related?' for nil:NilClass
```

You're trying to call the `related?` method on a nil object, in your case, Project. Your `create` method doesn't define `@project` anywhere.

UPDATE:

Your added code:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
```

will not find the correct project because the param `:id` refers to the ID of the task rather than its associated project. Remember, you're in `tasks_controller.rb`.

You'd need something like the following, assuming each Task has a reference to a Project via your `projecttask_id` field:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:projecttask_id])
```

Keep in mind that `projecttask_id` is kind of an odd way to name a foreign key. It would be less confusing to name it `project_id`.

Comment: thx mars...so i placed the line mentioned in the Update at the bottom to try and grab the ID, but now i get: 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#create
Couldn't find Project with 'id'=

Comment: @BB500 `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])`

Comment: hmmm thanks guys...that makes sense to me but its odd - i'm still getting the same error.  is there another file i can post to help debug this? (i tried both [:project_id] & [:projecttask_id])

Comment: I'm getting a faint whiff of pasta and tomato sauce here... Can you post the `task_params` method from your `tasks_controller.rb` (say so if you somehow don't have one)? You could be passing a bad `projecttask_id` -- are you sure a project exists? Where do you associate a task to a project? Does the user choose or are you doing it automatically somewhere?

Comment: sure just added it...hopefully my task_params are ok.   So the way it works is a user is on the project show page...then they click a button that takes them to the task new page in order to create the task.  So maybe the problem is in my form actually...(on the new task form it doesn't appear that it finds the project ID).

Comment: @BB500, i believe u have fixed at all ?

Comment: @BB500 Params look OK. Nothing you've said suggests that either you or your user associates a task to a project, however. That leaves you with some choices: a) add a Project field or pulldown to the task form and let your user choose b) [modify the `link_to`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378789/pass-parameters-in-link-to) that takes the user from Project form to the Task form so that it passes a `project_id` c) assign the Project in your `Task.rb` model depending on whatever criteria you need.

Comment: appreciate it...i will try modifying the link_to to pass the project_ID.  (& I'll go ahead and mark your original answer correct since it did solve the error in the title of the post).  thx,