# How to pass parameters using link_to through body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I currently have code similar to the following:

```
link_to "Test Link", params.merge(param1: "value1", param2: "value2")
```

This results in the following URL being generated:

***/test_url?param1=value1&param2=value2***

However, I want the following:

***/test_url#param1=value1&param2=value2***

and pass the parameters in the body of the post. How can I achieve this using link_to?

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378789/pass-parameters-in-link-to) post, however I need to use request.path() or something similar to get the current request URL and then append the anchor *#param1=value1&param2=value2* to the URL.

Any ideas on how I can go about this?

Comment: Do you want to add something to the body of the request or to the anchor of the link? Also do you want to send a GET or a POST request?

Comment: @mrzasa I want the parameters to be appended with a #, so that they are not read as a part of the URL. But I do want to pass the parameter values, but without explicitly adding to the link with '?'. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
link_to 'Test Link', current_action_url_or_path(anchor: { param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' })
```

Look your routes, use the path helper of the current page instead of current_action_url_or_path.

**UPDATE**

Try this way:

```
link_to 'Test Link', request.path + '#' + { param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }.to_query
```

Comment: Thanks @demir. However, I do not have the current_action_url or path as it is dynamically generated. That is the reason I wanted to use request.path(). But request.path() does not take any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `anchor` option to add a string after '#' and the [`Hash#to_query` method](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/Hash/to_query) to generate the query string.

```
link_to "Test Link", params.merge(anchor: {param1: "value1", param2: "value2"}.to_query)
```