# How to pass parameters through link_to using POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I want to pass parameters through link_to in rails. However, I don't want it to be a part of the URL. I went through the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378789/pass-parameters-in-link-to), however it does not help.

I am using a slim template and have something similar to this:

```
= link_to "Test", test_path(param1: "value1"), param2: 'value2', param3: value3, :method => :post
```

I want param1 to be a part of the URL, but not param2 and param3. However, `params[:param2]` or or `params[:param3]` gives me a blank value.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: "I want to pass parameters through link_to in rails. However, I don't want it to be a part of the URL." You want a thing that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
hidden_field_tag 'token', 'VUBJKB23UIVI1UU1VOBVI@' => <input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" value="VUBJKB23UIVI1UU1VOBVI@" />
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag

Comment: Read the question again - he is asking about using `link_to` not a form. Hidden inputs are also present in the URL when sending GET requests.